# The first list is not processed

Tags: list-manipulation

A randomly generated box[a,b] is in order[x] such that

```
order[x] = {{{2, 2}, {2, 1}, {1, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, 1}},
   {{5, 2}, {5, 3}, {4, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}},
   {{4, 2}, {4, 3}, {3, 2}, {1, 2}, {4, 1}},
   {{2, 1}, {2, 3}, {4, 3}, {5, 2}, {5, 3}}};
```

I want to add process A to each element in the order[x].
(e.g.

```
Table[Append[Flatten[order[x], 1][[i]], aaa], {i, 
  Length[Flatten[order[x], 1]]}]
```

)

At this time, I don't want to carry out processA when the  box[a,b] of first order[x].

(In this case, when it is `Table[order[x][[i, 1]], {i, Length[order[x]]}]`,process A doesn't work)

I thought I write  If statement by changing the 1 in `[[i, 1]]` to a letter (e.g. `[[i, y]]`), and write it as when `y = = 1`, but I don't know how to write it. I'm sorry for I can't explain well. I was wondering if you could help me.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I needed to process [x] in the form.

Comment: Is there a way to do this using the If syntax?

Comment: What is the meaning of "box"? What do you mean by "randomly generated box[a,b]"? You say that it's in "order[x]", so does `box[a,b]` really mean `{a,b}`?

Comment: What is the significance of "x"? Why do you use `order[x] = ...`? Why not just `order = ...`?

Comment: Are you wanting to change `order[x]` (or `order`), or are you wanting to do something with the `box` things? Are you saying that you want to apply `processA` to a `box` thing only if that `box` thing isn't in the first column of `order[x]`?

Comment: I posted a new QUESTION to write down exactly what I want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
order[x] =
  {{{2, 2}, {2, 1}, {1, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, 1}},
   {{5, 2}, {5, 3}, {4, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}},
   {{4, 2}, {4, 3}, {3, 2}, {1, 2}, {4, 1}},
   {{2, 1}, {2, 3}, {4, 3}, {5, 2}, {5, 3}}};
```

I'm not sure how the end result should look like, but maybe this is helpful:

Instead of the complicated `Table` construction you can use

```
list = Join @@ Map[Append[aaa], order[x], {2}]
```

{{2, 2, aaa}, {2, 1, aaa}, {1, 1, aaa}, {2, 3, aaa}, {3, 1, aaa}, {5,
2, aaa}, {5, 3, aaa}, {4, 1, aaa}, {1, 2, aaa}, {1, 3, aaa}, {4, 2,
aaa}, {4, 3, aaa}, {3, 2, aaa}, {1, 2, aaa}, {4, 1, aaa}, {2, 1,
aaa}, {2, 3, aaa}, {4, 3, aaa}, {5, 2, aaa}, {5, 3, aaa}}

Then you can post-process `list` according to your needs, for example:

Delete `aaa` if there is a `1` in the 2nd position

```
list /. {a_, 1, _} :> {a, 1}
```

{{2, 2, aaa}, {2, 1}, {1, 1}, {2, 3, aaa}, {3, 1}, {5, 2, aaa}, {5, 3,aaa}, {4, 1}, {1, 2, aaa}, {1, 3, aaa}, {4, 2, aaa}, {4, 3,
aaa}, {3, 2, aaa}, {1, 2, aaa}, {4, 1}, {2, 1}, {2, 3, aaa}, {4, 3,
aaa}, {5, 2, aaa}, {5, 3, aaa}}

Delete the whole triple

```
list /. {_, 1, _} :> Nothing
```

{{2, 2, aaa}, {2, 3, aaa}, {5, 2, aaa}, {5, 3, aaa}, {1, 2, aaa}, {1,
3, aaa}, {4, 2, aaa}, {4, 3, aaa}, {3, 2, aaa}, {1, 2, aaa}, {2, 3,
aaa}, {4, 3, aaa}, {5, 2, aaa}, {5, 3, aaa}}

**Revision**

based upon hare's comments:

```
order =
  {{{2, 2}, {2, 1}, {1, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, 1}},
   {{5, 2}, {5, 3}, {4, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}},
   {{4, 2}, {4, 3}, {3, 2}, {1, 2}, {4, 1}},
   {{2, 1}, {2, 3}, {4, 3}, {5, 2}, {5, 3}}};

res = MapAt[Append[aaa], order, {All, 2 ;;}];

res // MatrixForm
```

[image]

If you want to change the definition of `order`:

```
order = MapAt[Append[aaa], order, {All, 2 ;;}];

order[[1]]
```

{{2, 2}, {2, 1, aaa, aaa}, {1, 1, aaa, aaa}, {2, 3, aaa, aaa}, {3, 1, aaa, aaa}}

```
order[[2]]
```

{{5, 2}, {5, 3, aaa, aaa}, {4, 1, aaa, aaa}, {1, 2, aaa, aaa}, {1, 3, aaa, aaa}}

etc.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. 
order[x] = {{{2, 2}, {2, 1}, {1, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, 1}},
                {{5, 2}, {5, 3}, {4, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}},
                {{4, 2}, {4, 3}, {3, 2}, {1, 2}, {4, 1}},
                {{2, 1}, {2, 3}, {4, 3}, {5, 2}, {5, 3}}};
So, 
order[1] = {{2, 2}, {2, 1}, {1, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, 1}};
order[2] = {{5, 2}, {5, 3}, {4, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}};
order[3] = {{4, 2}, {4, 3}, {3, 2}, {1, 2}, {4, 1}};
order[4] = {{2, 1}, {2, 3}, {4, 3}, {5, 2}, {5, 3}};

Comment: I hope the End result is
order[1] = {{2, 2}, {{2, 1},aaa},{ {1, 1},aaa},{ {2, 3},aaa}, {{3, 1},aaa}};

order[2] = {{5, 2}, {{5, 3},aaa}, {{4, 1},,aaa} {{1, 2}, aaa},{{1, 3},aaa}};

order[3] = {{4, 2}, {{4, 3},aaa},{{3, 2},aaa}, {{1, 2},aaa},{{4, 1},aaa}};
order[4] = {{2, 1}, {{2, 3},aaa}, {{4, 3},aaa}, {{5, 2},aaa}, {{5, 3},aaa}};

Answer (score 1):

```
order[x] = {{{2, 2}, {2, 1}, {1, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, 1}}, {{5, 2}, {5, 
     3}, {4, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}}, {{4, 2}, {4, 3}, {3, 2}, {1, 2}, {4,
      1}}, {{2, 1}, {2, 3}, {4, 3}, {5, 2}, {5, 3}}};
```

**Using `Join`/`Append`:**

```
({First@#}~Join~(Append[aaa] /@ Rest@#)) & /@ order[x]
```

**Using `SequenceReplace`:**

```
SequenceReplace[#, {a_List, b__List} :>
    Sequence @@ {a, Sequence @@ Append[aaa] /@ {b}}
   ] & /@ order[x]
```

or

```
SequenceReplace[#, {a_List, b__List} :>
    Splice[{a, Splice[Map[Append[aaa]]@{b}]}]
   ] & /@ order[x]
```

**Using `SubsetMap`:**

```
SubsetMap[Map[Append[aaa]], #, 2 ;;] & /@ order[x]
```

---

*Result:*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I take it from your comment that you want a table of the form:

```
in = {{{2, 2}, {2, 1}, {1, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, 1}}, {{5, 2}, {5, 3}, {4, 
     1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}}, {{4, 2}, {4, 3}, {3, 2}, {1, 2}, {4, 
     1}}, {{2, 1}, {2, 3}, {4, 3}, {5, 2}, {5, 3}}};
```

change into a table :

[image]

This can be achieved by first change the structure of each row to {{elm1,elm2}},elm3,..}:

```
t = Prepend[#[[3 ;;]], #[[;; 2]]] & /@ in

{{{{2, 2}, {2, 1}}, {1, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, 1}}, {{{5, 2}, {5, 3}}, {4, 
   1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}}, {{{4, 2}, {4, 3}}, {3, 2}, {1, 2}, {4, 
   1}}, {{{2, 1}, {2, 3}}, {4, 3}, {5, 2}, {5, 3}}}
```

And then we can append "aaa" to every element on the second level:

```
t= Map[Append[#, aaa] &, t, {2}];
t// ColumnForm

{
 {{{{2, 2}, {2, 1}, aaa}, {1, 1, aaa}, {2, 3, aaa}, {3, 1, aaa}}},
 {{{{5, 2}, {5, 3}, aaa}, {4, 1, aaa}, {1, 2, aaa}, {1, 3, aaa}}},
 {{{{4, 2}, {4, 3}, aaa}, {3, 2, aaa}, {1, 2, aaa}, {4, 1, aaa}}},
 {{{{2, 1}, {2, 3}, aaa}, {4, 3, aaa}, {5, 2, aaa}, {5, 3, aaa}}}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a total stab in the dark, but maybe it'll help us clarify the problem.

```
processA[box[a_, b_]] := processedBox[a, b, "aaa"] /; MemberQ[order[x][[All, 1]], {a, b}];
processA[b_box] := unprocessedBox[b]

processA[box[2, 2]]
(* processedBox[2, 2, "aaa"] *)

processA[box[5, 3]]
(* unprocessedBox[box[5, 3]] *)
```