# How not to process the first list?

Tags: list-manipulation

(I reconsidered my previous question as it didn't describe well what I wanted to implement.So I repost this)

There is a box [a,b] in order[x] generated in a random sequence.

```
    order[x] = {{{2, 2}, {2, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 2}},{{3, 2}, {3, 1}, {4, 1}, {1, 2}},{{4, 2}, {1,1}, {1, 2}, {2, 2}},
{{2, 1}, {4, 2}, {1, 2},{1, 1}}};

(order[1] = {{2, 2}, {2, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 2}}
order[2] = {{3, 2}, {3, 1}, {4, 1}, {1, 2}}
order[3] = {{4, 2}, {1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 2}}
order[4] = {{2, 1}, {4, 2}, {1, 2}, {1, 1}})
```

Each of the elements is also contained in box[a,b].
(e.g.

```
box[1,1]={2,5,10}
box[1,2]={3,65,10}
box[2,1]={2,5,6}
box[2,2]={2,45,10}
box[3,1]={3,25,10}
box[3,2]={12,5,6}
box[4,1]={9,5,10}
box[4,2]={3,5,10}
```

)
Based on the order of the randomly generated order[x], another process (processA) is carry out.
For example, adding one of the elements of the previous box[a,b] to the back box[a,b].
(So, in the case of `order[1][[2]]`,

`box[2, 1] = Flatten[Append[box[2, 1], RandomSample[box[2, 2], 1]], 1]`
.
in the case of `order[1][[3]]`,

```
box[1, 1] = Flatten[Append[box[1, 1], RandomSample[box[1, 2], 1]], 1]
```

.

at that time, elements of the box[a,b] are updated little by little.)

I want to continue this kind of processing without being reset. (Meaning of reset that `order[1][[4]]` after processing and `order[2][[4]]` before processing have the same value.)

My question starts here,
The box[a,b] at the beginning of each count (i.e. the box[a,b] at position order[i][[1]]) doesn't need to work ProcessA because there is no box in front of it.

I wanted to make a program like this, using if statements to make it work like

```
If[box[a,b]==order[i][[1]],
```

→ no operation

```
If[box[a,b]!=order[i][[1]],
```

→ProcessA work

However, I can't write code well.
Sorry for beating around the bush.
I was wondering if you could help me.

Comment: *WHICH* previous question?

Comment: that is https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/292349/91918

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, if I'm understanding your question, it's quite a bit more complicated than just "not processing the first list". First, let's do a bit of setup and make data structures that are better suited to the problem, but we'll start with your data structures for clarity.

```
order[x] = 
  {{{2, 2}, {2, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 2}}, 
   {{3, 2}, {3, 1}, {4, 1}, {1, 2}}, 
   {{4, 2}, {1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 2}}, 
   {{2, 1}, {4, 2}, {1, 2}, {1, 1}}};
box[1, 1] = {2, 5, 10};
box[1, 2] = {3, 65, 10};
box[2, 1] = {2, 5, 6};
box[2, 2] = {2, 45, 10};
box[3, 1] = {3, 25, 10};
box[3, 2] = {12, 5, 6};
box[4, 1] = {9, 5, 10};
box[4, 2] = {3, 5, 10};
```

As an aside, you said that `order[x]` was created randomly, and you can do that like this:

```
RandomChoice[Tuples[{Range@4, Range@2}], {4, 4}]
```

Now, let's clean things up. We don't need the `x`, and the `box` expressions can be thought of as just extracting part of a larger structure.

```
sequences = order[x];
(* Or alternatively
   sequences = RandomChoice[Tuples[{Range@4, Range@2}], {4, 4}]
 *)

boxes = Table[box[i, j], {i, 4}, {j, 2}]
(*
  {{{2, 5, 10}, {3, 65, 10}}, 
   {{2, 5, 6}, {2, 45, 10}}, 
   {{3, 25, 10}, {12, 5, 6}}, 
   {{9, 5, 10}, {3, 5, 10}}}
*)
```

So, now you have a data structure called `boxes` for which `box[x,y]` is equal to `boxes[[x,y]]`.

Now we need a way to update one position in this structure based on the value at another position. Specifically, we want to get a random selection from what's in the list at that other location and append it to the list in our target location. So, we might write a function like this:

```
UpdateBoxes[boxes_, updateLocation_, chooseLocation_] :=
  MapAt[Append[RandomChoice[Extract[boxes, chooseLocation]]], boxes, updateLocation]
```

Now, we want to repeat this process by going through a list of positions. This sounds like a `Fold` operation. But we need to "remember" which location we previously updated and use it as the choice location. To do that, we might use a `FoldPair`. But we'll need a slightly different form of our `UpdateBoxes`, because `FoldPair` uses a very specific structure. You may need to read the documentation to understand what's going on here, but for now, I'll just show you what I did:

```
UpdateBoxesForFold[{boxes_, chooseLocation_}, updateLocation_] :=
  {Null, {UpdateBoxes[boxes, updateLocation, chooseLocation], updateLocation}}
```

And now we can apply the fold. Our `sequences` actually has four sequences, so we'll only do this one at a time. As an example, I'll just do the first one:

```
theSeq = sequences[[1]];
result = FoldPair[UpdateBoxesForFold, {boxes, First@theSeq}, Rest@theSeq, Extract[{-1, 1}]]
```

Alternatively, if you really do want the side effect of updating your `box` definitions, then we could use a simpler mechanism but with more global complications. We can write a function to update `box` definitions based on a pair of "coordinates":

```
UpdateBox[chooseBox : {c1_, c2_}, updateBox : {u1_, u2_}] :=
  box[u1, u2] = Append[box[u1, u2], RandomChoice[box[c1, c2]]]
```

(The argument names `chooseBox` and `updateBox` are just there for clarity.)

Now we can apply to adjacent pairs from your `order` structure (and again I'm just doing the first row):

```
BlockMap[Apply[UpdateBox], theSeq, 2, 1]
```

You can check with

```
Definition[box]
(*
  box[1, 1] = {2, 5, 10, 2}
  box[1, 2] = {3, 65, 10, 5}
  box[2, 1] = {2, 5, 6, 2}
  box[2, 2] = {2, 45, 10}
  box[3, 1] = {3, 25, 10}
  box[3, 2] = {12, 5, 6}
  box[4, 1] = {9, 5, 10}
  box[4, 2] = {3, 5, 10}
*)
```

**Addressing the comment**

> Is there any way of using If?

Using `If` actually makes this more complicated. In your question, you were wondering about a form like this:

```
If[box[a,b]==order[i][[1]]
```

But that won't work at all, because `order` contains something analogous to coordinate pairs, but `box[a,b]` for some values of `a` and `b` will evaluate to a list (initially a triple). What you really want to do is check something like this: When I'm looking at `order[[a,b]]` is `b` equal to `1`? This suggests that you're looping with an index variable. Well, okay, we could do that:

```
Do[
  If[1 < idx, UpdateBox[theSeq[[idx - 1]], theSeq[[idx]]], Null],
  {idx, 4}]
```

But it would be easier to just change the range of the `idx` variable:

```
Do[
  UpdateBox[theSeq[[idx - 1]], theSeq[[idx]]],
  {idx, 2, 4}]
```

So, I don't see how force-fitting an `If` in there somewhere is helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your help. however, Is there any way of using If?

Comment: see the updates.

Comment: Thank you, but I can't find how to use UpdateBox statement. UpdateBox is not statement? UpdateBox is the same as "updateBox"?

Comment: I defined `UpdateBox` in my answer.